# Why bones IK change positions by itself?

Tags: rigging, armature, bones, constraints

I am done with the rigging on my mesh with bones parented with empty groups. But, when I start creating the keyframes in the animation. the bones position change very oddly by themselves.

This is the keyframes I have created
[image]

And this is how appears automatically in the animation
[image]

After this I have to apply <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> "TWICE" to reset them.

Does anybody knows why and how to solve this?

Thanks in advance

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When an IK chain change position in weird ways, it's because of one of this problems:

- the ik traget location is modified by the movements of one bone of the chain itself: so there is an endless circularity. Check if it has constraints related to any bone of the chain, or if it is child of a bone related to the chain.
- some bends have a flipped position that can resolve the IK request, so you need to establish a pole target to have full control of the behaviour of the chain

Comment: Hi Josh. Thank you.Yes I think it has to be something related with the constraints because The machine has three arms holding the bucket, so I tried to parent them to the bucket which is like three different bones parented to one vertex group. I will post images in the post (bottom) so you can see what I am talking about. I think those bones are causing interference to each other. Do you know a better way to parent those three arms of the machine to the bucket? How can I Make this three arms (right arm, left arm, last central arm)  get attached to one single vertices group which is the bucket?

Comment: Right and left arm should have the same dynamic of movements but the central arm is different. this should rotate the bucket in its own axes.

Comment: If you need more help I think you should upload your .blend file: it's difficult to understand the rig from the pictures